# jQuery add if statement to post function

Tags: jquery, if-statement, post

I programmed the following:

```
$.post("helmscript.php", { voorhoofdomtrek: voorhoofdomtrek, leverancier: leverancier, categorie:categorie
}, func......
```

However, i need an if statement like this in the post function:

```
$.post("helmscript.php", { if (variableX == true) {voorhoofdomtrek: voorhoofdomtrek,} leverancier: leverancier, categorie:categorie
}, func......
```

But an if statement in the post function does not work. Could you guys help out?

Comment: Why don't you set your check before the `$.post` method???

Comment: Please state what you actually want to do that prevents you from doing the if outside the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize an object and populate data in object based on your condition and then pass it in the post request.

Please check this code.

```
var data = {};
if (variableX == true) {data.voorhoofdomtrek = voorhoofdomtrek;}
data.leverancier = leverancier;
data.categorie = categorie;

$.post("helmscript.php", data, func......
```

Comment: Wow! That so easy, couldn't come up with this solution for two days. Thanks so much!

Comment: Most welcome. I am really happy that it is useful to you.

Comment: Your `data` should be an object, not an array. And i don't see the purpose of `JSON.stringify()` here

Comment: But how can i read this array with variables in my php file? ( where it's posted to) I need to do a check for each variable in the array in the php file. I can't figure it out

Comment: Ohh I see. I replaced the array with javascript object. Can you please check with updated answer. And in your php file you will find the values with $_POST

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as @A. Wolf said.

Set the condition before , see my psuedocode

You can also use var data array = {}  first and then implemnet it , see below answers .

```
 if (variableX == true) 
 {
$.post("helmscript.php",voorhoofdomtrek: voorhoofdomtrek, leverancier: leverancier, categorie:categorie
  }, func......
 }
 else
 {
  //do some content here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is, there are around 500 variables. And in every (post) situation (like 200 different ones) there is a different combination of those variables. So te keep it generic, i need to set if statements in the post request. Otherwise i need to write out 200 different post requests with all kind of variable combinations.